# PL SQL - Using one macro input to get two columns

Tags: plsqldeveloper

Let's say you have three columns in your table.
Call them col1, col2, and col3.
Let's say you want to reference only two of them, and do so with only one macro input, called &value (see sample query below).
So, if your input is 2, you would reference col2 and col1.
If your input is 3, then you would reference col3 and col2.

Here is a sample query...
select col&value,
       col&value-1
from table
;

So after I input the macro value = 2, the query would look like this...
select col2,
       col1
from table
;

Here my problem...
I don't believe I can use the field called 
col&value-1.

Is there a correct way to address this dilemma without having two macro inputs?

Thanks! I appreciate your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please a) format your code as a code block; and b) tell us what did you try (what exactly is does the _don't believe_ mean).

Comment: The sample query I show above is the whole code. It is a sample, rather than what I tried to do.